A supernatural fantasy martial arts comic where a young man meditates and wakes up on an Earth with monsters and gods
I read this comic almost 2 to 3 years ago. I believe this comic was full colour.
A young man starts to meditate. When he wakes up from meditation, he finds that the whole Earth has changed and the area he is in has monsters roaming around. There are gods and goddesses (maybe Chinese or Japanese deities) that humans pray to and pay tribute to.
In chapter 2 (maybe) there was a strong rain and it was said that the water dragon god was crying. It is revealed that "it was a mere show-off, since the dead was one of his sons which he did not even care about." (This was revealed by a beautiful goddess, whose name I don't remember.)
This young guy came across a creature who was killing any human he could get and stuffing them into a pocket in front of his belly. (It had a belly sack like a kangaroo.) This young guy kills the monster, but gets in trouble for doing so, because the monster was a familiar or slave monster of the beautiful goddess. They later decide to teach this young man the current hierarchy of the world, and decide he has to pay a heavy tribute to appease the hurt ego of the goddess.

An anonymous user has attempted to edit this question. If that person is you, and you've lost access to the account you used to post this question, please merge your accounts by following the instructions provided here. Once the accounts are merged, you'll regain the ability to edit this question without approval from others, leave comments within this thread, and mark an answer as accepted, if one is posted.
